# Insert into.. Select from.. Hangs - Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I have a simple insert statement which works fine on DEV_1 Database but hangs when being executed on DEV_2 database.

The select statement returns 200 rows and takes 7 seconds to execute.
Have already checked for locks.

```
INSERT INTO test_table
SELECT account
FROM   table_1 a,
       table_2 q,
       table_3 c
WHERE  a.bkg_date = q.prev_working_day
AND    a.branch_code = q.branch_code
AND    a.account = c.ref_no
AND    a.account NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT x.account
                         FROM   table_1 x,
                                (SELECT a.account,
                                        MAX(a.bkg_date) bkg_date
                                 FROM   table_1 a,
                                        table_4 b
                                 WHERE  a.lcy_closing_bal < 0
                                 AND    a.account = b.cust_ac_no
                                 GROUP  BY a.account) y
                         WHERE  x.account = y.account
                         AND    x.bkg_date > y.bkg_date
                         AND    x.lcy_closing_bal >= 0 HAVING COUNT(x.account) > 1
                         GROUP  BY x.account);
```

I have also tried to use a create table as select.. which works fine. I want to understand how come the Create table works but the insert is hanging.

```
Create table abc as
( select ...)
```

Comment: how did you check for locks? My guess is that there's a lock on the table you're trying to insert into. Also, please get into the habit of listing the columns you'll be inserting into (it's just about ok to not list them for one-off test inserts, but I'd still recommend you list the columns), because not doing so in production code is a potential bug, if someone were to add a new column to the table being inserted into.

Comment: have you checked the execution plans? A plan with rowsource statistics (for example created with the use of a gather_plan_statistics hint) should tell you where the time is spend in the execution. Sometimes two systems with the same data show a different behaviour. And sometimes an insert and a corresponding CTAS operation show a different behaviour.

Comment: In Oracle a "hang" like this usually means you have an open transaction somewhere and you need to commit it.